# I.9 doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

everyone! My minecraft doesn't work. 1.8.8 and below work, **But 1.9 does not work**. I open a world or server, and it crashes. here is the full crash report.

```
    at bfb.p(SourceFile:381) [1.9.jar:?]
    at bcf.t(SourceFile:1575) [1.9.jar:?]
    at bcf.av(SourceFile:962) [1.9.jar:?]
    at bcf.a(SourceFile:392) [1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [1.9.jar:?]
[20:08:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.9
[20:08:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[20:08:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[20:08:29] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
[20:08:30] [Server thread/INFO]: sonic_xerox[local:E:cd1ac7ef] logged in with entity id 122 at (200.35301097054491, 18.050912536344374, 176.30000001192093)
[20:08:30] [Server thread/INFO]: sonic_xerox joined the game
[20:08:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving and pausing game...
[20:08:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'simple test'/Overworld
[20:08:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'simple test'/Nether
[20:08:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'simple test'/The End
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff951684fdc, pid=7196, tid=8056
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x524fdc]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7196.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: Are you running Intel graphics?  If so, that's why you can't start Minecraft.

Answer (score -2):

I know how to fix this. It's that mini-dump thing. Here is how you fix it (I ask this and my friend helped me so let's share the solution): there is to ways. I did the second way go to settings/options in minecraft then  find video settings then press use VBO. It should say enabled I believe. There you go! Have fun with 1.9 :)